# Drawing textured quad with OpenGL / LWJGL uses old texture

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

I'm drawing a texture quad, but the texture used is one that was bound previously, even if I'm trying to bind a new texture.

Creating the texture in GuiHandler.java

```
    tex = GL11.glGenTextures();
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(new File("res/gui.png"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PNGDecoder decoder = null;
    try {
        decoder = new PNGDecoder(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(4 * decoder.getWidth()
            * decoder.getHeight());
    try {
        decoder.decode(buffer, decoder.getWidth() * 4,
                PNGDecoder.Format.RGBA);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    buffer.flip();
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
            GL11.GL_RGB8, decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getHeight(), 0,
            GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

The rendering code

```
GL11.glPushAttrib(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GuiHandler.tex);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(gui.getX(), gui.getY());
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(gui.getX()+gui.getWidth(), gui.getY());
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(gui.getX()+gui.getWidth(), gui.getY()+gui.getHeight());
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(gui.getX(), gui.getY()+gui.getHeight());
    //GL11.glRectf(gui.getX(), gui.getY(), gui.getWidth()+gui.getWidth(), gui.getY() + gui.getHeight());
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glPopAttrib();
```

Does anyone know why a previously bound texture is being used instead of the right one?
P.S I'm using LWJGL

Answer (score 0):

Your texture creation code does actually *not* bind the newly created texture object, but updates the one previously bound.

Comment: @VivaDaylight3: just call `glBindTexture` after you created the new texture object (but before the `glTexParameter` and `glTexImage` calls). However, I'm not sure if you really even want to create a new texture object per frame - you might need just one which is updated, by I can't tell without further context.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting the same result :/ Thanks for the reply though